# Can we use serializer_class attribute with APIView(django rest framework)?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

As per the DRF documentation, the `serializer_class` attribute should be set when using GenericAPIView. But why does the `serializer_class` attribute even works with `APIView`?

Here is my API code:

```
class UserView(APIView):

    serializer_class = SignupSerializer

    @transaction.atomic
    def post(self, request):
        email = get_data_param(request, 'email', None)
        password = get_data_param(request, 'password', None)

        params = request.POST.copy()
        params["username"] = email

        serializer = UserSerializer(data=params)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            user = serializer.save()
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            params["user"] = user.id

        serializer = CustomProfileSerializer(data=params)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            profile = serializer.save()
            return Response(response_json(True, profile.to_dict(), None))

class SignupSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=100)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
```

When I browse this API in the browser it does show the `email` and `password` fields as input but if I don't set this `serializer_class` attribute, no input fields are shown. 
Ideally, this `serializer_class` attribute should not work with `APIView`. I have searched a lot but there is nothing available related to this.

Can anyone please provide an explanation for this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: There is no mention of serializer_class in the source for APIView or it's parent class View.  You're creating a class variable "serializer_class" there, so I can only guess that you must be referencing that (directly or indirectly) somewhere else in the code you have not shown.

Comment: Why do you think the APIView wouldn't use the serializer class? It still has to determine what your data looks like and how to serialize it. You should be using a serializer class with APIView. You might be better off using one of the generic views over APIView as well.

Comment: @tyebillion: i have updated the code which shows the complete version

Comment: @electrometro: APIView should not be using serializer_class attribute because there is no mention of it in the DRF documentation. Only GenericAPIView has this functionality. But the behavior of APIVIew with and without that serializer_class attribute is different. When i declare that attribute with APIView, it behaves like a GenericAPIView, it shows the 2 input fields i.e. Email and password in the browser when i browse that API. Whereas if i don't declare that serializer_class attribute with APIView, those 2 input fields are not shown in web browser.

Answer (score 3):

I think this can help you.
create serializer.py and write:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password')
```

and views.py:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

from .serializers import UserSerializer
from .models import User


class AddUserAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        user_serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if user_serializer.is_valid():
            user = user_serializer.save() 
            user.set_password(user_serializer.data["password"])
            return Response({'message': 'user added successfully!'})

        return Response({'message': user_serializer.errors})
```

Comment: This is so simple, I love it!

Answer (score 2):

**You are absolutely right!!**:
`APIView` doesn't utilize a `serializer_class` (by default) because it is not meant to handle any request processing logic!

What happens though is that the [`BrowsableAPIRenderer`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#browsableapirenderer) that is used to render the API in the browser checks for a `serializer_class` attribute and set's it as the View serializer if it exists. We can see this in the `BrowsableAPIRenderer` code:

1. The [`_get_serializer`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/00cd4ef864a8bf6d6c90819a983017070f9f08a5/rest_framework/renderers.py#L438) class of the renderer:

   > ```
   > def _get_serializer(self, serializer_class, view_instance, request, *args, **kwargs):
   >     kwargs['context'] = {
   >        'request': request,
   >        'format': self.format,
   >        'view': view_instance
   >    }
   >    return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
   > ```
2. And the way it is used to set the renderer serializer if it exists, inside the `get_rendered_html_form`:

   - [Line 483](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/00cd4ef864a8bf6d6c90819a983017070f9f08a5/rest_framework/renderers.py#L483): `has_serializer_class = getattr(view, 'serializer_class', None)`
   - [Lines 497 to 509](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/00cd4ef864a8bf6d6c90819a983017070f9f08a5/rest_framework/renderers.py#L497):

     > ```
     > if has_serializer:
     >     if method in ('PUT', 'PATCH'):
     >         serializer = view.get_serializer(instance=instance, **kwargs)
     >     else:
     >         serializer = view.get_serializer(**kwargs)
     > else:
     >     # at this point we must have a serializer_class
     >     if method in ('PUT', 'PATCH'):
     >         serializer = self._get_serializer(view.serializer_class, view,
     >                                           request, instance=instance, **kwargs)
     >     else:
     >         serializer = self._get_serializer(view.serializer_class, view,
     >                                           request, **kwargs)
     > ```

In essence, you accidentally override the `BrowserAPIRenderer`'s default behavior regarding the `APIView` by providing the `serializer_class` attribute. For what is worth, my opinion on the matter is that this should not be possible!

Answer (score 2):

I use the django rest framework default `get_schema_view()` to provide auto-generated `openapi` schema from which I auto generate a javascript client for.

This works for ViewSets, but the payload wasn't being provided for views defined by `APIView`.

Where I have defined serializers, I found that adding `get_serializer()` method to my APIView classes allowed the schema to be generated with the serializer defined payload.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

from .serializers import UserSerializer
from .models import User


class AddUserAPIView(APIView):
    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return UserSerializer(*args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request):
        user_serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if user_serializer.is_valid():
            user = user_serializer.save() 
            user.set_password(user_serializer.data["password"])
            return Response({'message': 'user added successfully!'})

        return Response({'message': user_serializer.errors})
```